# Batch script to change MD5 of all files in every folder

Tags: batch-file, md5, checksum

I am using this to change the MD5 of all .rar-files.

```
FOR %%a in (*.rar) do ECHO.>> %%a
```

The problem is: The *.bat has to be in the folder where the .rar-files are, but I want to put the *.bat into root.

```
ROOT
 |----Folder1
          |------*.rar
 |----Folder2
          |------*.rar
 |----Folder3
          |------*.rar
```

How do I have to change the code that it changes the MD5 of every *.rar that is in every folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /r ROOT %%a in (*.rar) do echo.>>"%%~fa"
```

should do that job...

(but I'd remove the `>>` first as a test to echo the filenames that would be affected - just as a test...)

Comment: This works too: `FOR /r %%a in (*.rar) do ECHO.>> %%a`
Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: Certainly. Adding in a subdirecory name (eg. ROOT) after the `/r` would allow you to execute your function on a subtree anywhere - omitting it will operate from the current directory.